# Three.js toDataUrl blank

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, getimagedata

When I try to save an image from a three.js WebGl render it comes out totally blank, but it does return a ton of characters:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAK8AAADICAYAAACeY7GXAAADt0lEQ…IF4M2+znB4GcgWgDf7OsPhZSBbAN7s6wyHl4FsAXizrzP8AS/TAMmecuTCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

I do have the preserveDrawingBuffer set to true like so:

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { 
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
} );
```

And this is how I am calling the toDataUrl:

```
var getImageData = false;
function render() {

            //camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .005;
            //camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .005;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
             if(getImageData == true){
                imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.setTimeout(10);
                console.log(imgData);
                getImageData = false;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }


           getImageData = true;
```

And here is the what the canvas looks like, before rendered to an image:

Canvas
[image: canvas]

CanvasCode

```
<canvas width="175" height="200" style="width: 175px; height: 200px"></canvas>
```

Honestly I am not sure what else to say other than, any ideas as to why the image is coming up as totally blank? The render() function is the very last thing at the bottom of the code.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to render the image, I have googled around and tried a few different ways to do it, still all ways make a blank image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL is an asynchronous API. Thus you need either add `gl.finish()` (which can worsen performance) call before calling `toDataUrl()` or call it on the next frame. To do so you for example can use `setTimeout` (you've that, but doing it incorrectly):

```
if(getImageData == true) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log(imgData);
    }, 100);
    getImageData = false;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, it just says gl, webgl, etc is not defined. I also tried THREE.finish() and that didn't work either.

Comment: @brandoncox try setTimeout. I've edited answer to include a code snippet.

Comment: I get this error: [.CommandBufferContext.Offscreen-MainThread-038CA608]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0

Comment: @brandoncox Do you a have a page I can look at to help?

Comment: I changed it from 100ms to 200 and it worked, I guess 100 just wasn't long enough for the texture to load. Thanks!